# HTML "getElementByID" implementation for SWT widget

Tags: java, swt

In HTML, there is something like `document.getElementById("button1");`

I would like something of this sort to happen in my SWT application.

Say I created an SWT widget on the run with `new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH)`
Is there anywhere I can get(reference) this object with something similar to `getElementById(...)`?

I am thinking of creating a `HashMap<String, Object>` type, where String places the id of the object(Widget) and then I will call `hashMap.getKey(id)` which will return me a reference to the object(Widget).

Answer (score 0):

No, SWT widgets don't have ids or anything similar. Of course, you can do it manually using a map, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to implement such a functionality without any big efforts. As an example-implementation you can use SWTBot (a GUI-Testing API for SWT) that has several methods to "find" Widgets by a given id.

Download the SWTBot Source-Code (see http://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Contributing#Getting_the_source) and take a look for example at `org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBot.buttonWithId(String, String, int)` If you navigate through the implementation you'll get an idea how this can be implemented...

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively check all the children of a composite with a method like this one, and use [Widget.getData()/setData()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html) to set an id:

```
public <T extends Control> T findChild(Composite parent, String id) {
    Control found = null;
    Control[] children = parent.getChildren();
    for (int i = 0; i < children .length && found == null; i++) {
        Control child = children[i];
        if (id.equals(child.getData(ID)) {
            found = child;
        } else if (child instanceof Composite) {
            found = findChild((Composite) child, id);
        }
    }
    return (T) found ;
}
```